# CSS cant hide background

Tags: css

I am trying to hide the body until the page is loaded, however, when the background image for the body starts loading it ignores the display: none I've set for the body and shows it anyway.

Body CSS

```
body {

    background-image: url("../img/backgrounds/authentication/main.jpg");

}
```

Body HTML:

```
<body style="display: none;">
```

Comment: You could try giving the body height=0 and than do an onload function like `document.onload=function(){ body.style.height="100%"};`

Comment: For better answers, profide a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

If the `<html>` element has no `background` attached to it, the `background` of the document will be **taken** from the `<body>` element instead.

By default, the `<html>` element has no `background` attached to it. Thus, when you set `style="display:none;"`, the HTML element will need some background to be rendered to screen and will thus **take** the background of the `<body>` element.

A simple solution is to set the `background-color` of the `<html>` element to be some color that is **not transparent (i.e the default "color")**. [Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating this.](https://jsfiddle.net/hw6hyqh3/2/) (simply remove the `display: none` in the `html` code to reveal the image)

Hope this helped. :)

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for, its a bit of a hack. But thanks for your input any way

Comment: No problem! :) you could then create an onload function or a simple javascript file that executes when the document is ready, that changes the `display` attribute. Alternatively, you could use the `opacity` attribute, which is a better fit for transitioning (they are pretty much identical attributes since the `body` element is a "root" element anyway) :)

Answer (score 1):

In your html, give attribute `hidden` to the body.

```
<body hidden>

</body>
```

Also, make sure your html is correct (all tags are closed properly) and that everything is inside body.

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving the body a height=0 and than do an onload function like

`document.onload=function(){ body.style.height="100%"};`

If you are interested you could also give jQuery and the fadeIn fadeOut function a shot ;)

Comment: Does not seem to fully load the full height of the image sadly, for some reason

Comment: Jm can you than add a screenshot and more details about your html structure maybe? Maybe you have to set also background-size in css

Answer (score 0):

Follow this: "https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/load-background-image-after-content-loads/240343/3" and also "https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html" may be this will solved your problem.

**Else just add following in your css.**

```
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}
body:after {
    content:"";
    background: url(http://yourimage-url.jpg ) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-1;
    animation:bgFade 2s 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes bgFade {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    } 
}
```